# Error in installing pip package with setup.py requirements

Tags: python, pip, package

I'm trying to install the [aptdaemon](https://pypi.org/project/aptdaemon) package on Ubuntu `20.04` as follows: `pip3 install aptdaemon` but I'm getting an error:

`error in setup.cfg: command 'build' has no such option 'i18n'`

I have installed both `python3-distutils` and `python3-distutils-extra`:

```
sudo apt install --reinstall python3-distutils
sudo apt install --reinstall python3-distutils-extra
```

but still the error appears.

Can you please tell me how can I get rid of this error in setup.py build requirements? thanks in advance.

Comment: Contact the authors of the project to ask them how it should be installed.

Comment: @sinoroc your kind advice solved my problem

Comment: Good. One might wonder why this project is distributed on _PyPI_, if it is not meant to be *pip*-installed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is to use Ubuntu `aptdaemon` package that is provided in the Ubuntu repositories:

```
sudo apt install aptdaemon
sudo apt install python3-aptdaemon
```

[Credit to this answer](https://answers.launchpad.net/aptdaemon/+question/705580)

Answer (score 0):

Open file `setup.cfg` look for section called `[build]` and inside this section you will find line called `i18n = 1` remove this line then save thie changes then try to install again

because the error suggests that it is `i18n = 1`

Comment: Run pip3 install --upgrade pip to make sure you installed the latest version then sudo apt-get install build-essential python3-dev to install the build dependencies required by many Python packages.